# What is the construct `(0, fn)()` where fn is a function?

Tags: javascript

In some JavaScript code, I saw

```
function fn() { console.log("yes") }
(0, fn)();
```

the `fn` was something else but I just make a simple one here in this question.  What does the 2 lines above mean -- that is, why do we do something like `(0, fn)();` ?

Comment: It does seem to be the same question, but since there isn't really a very good answer on that one, I vote this question does NOT get closed and hopefully some brilliant js programmer will explain if the 0 actually performs any real function here rather than just unnecessarily bloating the code. I mean, this is a completely legitimate (and good) question.

Comment: Short answer is the second line is exactly the same as `fn();`, but there must be a valid reason to do this. Old browsers benefit from this somehow or something along those lines... ?